# How to get rid of stray &raquo; Character in a List

Tags: css

My document has stray `&raquo;` appearing at the beginning of each list element. When I view source in the browser the character is not in the document -- it only appears on screen.

How can I get rid of it?

Do I use `list-style-postion` somehow?

I have tried everything I can think of in css:

```
list-style:none !important;
list-style-type:none !important;
list-style-image:none !important;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably added by a `:before` pseudo element.

Look for something like

```
li:before {
    ...
}
```

and remove it

Comment: Thanks @ZoltanToth. I learned something new. That was the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This should reset/clear up the lists

```
ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd
{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
list-style-position: inside;
list-style-image: none;
}
```

See if any pseudo selector is used to add them.